# How can I re install Tiger without the original install or recovery DVDs?

Tags: imac, install, macos

I have an iMac (PPC) with iSight. How can I re install Tiger without the original install or recovery DVDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find Tiger DVDs in order to install the OS, friends and eBay (or its moral equivalent in your country) are a good place to start.

Comment: is there a way to create an install dvd from my current installed OS ?

Comment: None that I know of. The OS on the DVDs from Apple are composed of compressed packaged that the installer disk manages, sets permissions upon installation, etc. @Bao's disk image idea is the only other way to go, as well making sure you have a mirror image of your drive for easy backup.

Comment: thks @Philip ; if I want to use an image as @Bao suggests, what should be the format / process ?

Comment: You can use Disk Utility to make an image of a disk, which makes the process as simple as possible (instructions go beyond the scope of comments). But like @Bao wrote, you need the disk to make the image no matter what if you can't borrow one from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway to install Tiger on your iMac you will need to get an image of it and try to make it bootable on other devices (if you don't want to use DVD). But the easiest way remains finding out the Tiger DVD.